# Least squares fit of cumulative density function to some quantiles

Tags: python, scipy

Supposing a user gives some percentiles of a distribution like this, and we are trying to find the parameters of the distribution.

```
# a list of (p,x) tuples, where P(X<x)=p
percentiles = [(0.2,8),(0.4,12),(0.5,16),(0.9,30)]
```

The user specifies the family of the distribution (e.g. Normal). When there are more than 2 percentiles, the equation system is over-determined, so we'll want to find parameters that fit the input best, based on least squares.

I'm having trouble implementing this. In this minimal example below, `curve_fit` just returns the default value of 1 for both parameters. What am I doing wrong?

```
from scipy import stats
from scipy import optimize

# a list of (p,x) tuples, where P(X<x)=p
percentiles = [(0.2,8),(0.4,12),(0.5,16),(0.9,30)]

fit = optimize.curve_fit(
            lambda x,mu,sigma: stats.norm(mu,sigma).cdf(x),
            xdata=[x[1] for x in percentiles],
            ydata=[x[0] for x in percentiles])
print(fit[0])
```

**Edit**: JohanC pointed out that I the initial guesses are important. Here's the (crude) method I used to get an initial guess for the parameters from the user's input:

```
def percentiles_to_list(percentiles):
    out =[]
    i = 1
    c = 1
    for p,q in percentiles:
        if c == len(percentiles):
            number_to_append = int(100 - i)
        else:
            number_to_append = int(p*100-i)
        out += [q]*number_to_append
        i = p*100
        c += 1
    return out

def initial_guess(percentiles):
    lis = percentiles_to_list(percentiles)
    mean = np.mean(lis)
    stdev = np.std(lis)
    return mean,stdev
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain a good fit, initial guesses for [`curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) are important.  Here, the given 50% percentile is a perfect initial guess for `mu`. For `sigma` we can take any reasonable initial guess. The default guesses are all `1`s, which seem too far off in this case. Apart from (or *instead of*) an initial guess, also parameter boundaries can be set for `curve_fit`.

Note that due to the strict monotonic function we could switch the role of `x` and `y` to check whether that would give a more satisfactory fit.

The following code tries both fits and shows the result graphically. Both coincide quite strong.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from scipy import optimize

# a list of (p,x) tuples, where P(X<x)=p
percentiles = [(0.2, 8), (0.4, 12), (0.5, 16), (0.9, 30)]

fit_params_ppf, _fit_covariances = optimize.curve_fit(lambda x, mu, sigma: stats.norm(mu, sigma).ppf(x),
                                                      xdata=[percent for percent, percentile in percentiles],
                                                      ydata=[percentile for percent, percentile in percentiles],
                                                      p0=[16, 8])
plt.scatter([percentile for percent, percentile in percentiles], [percent for percent, percentile in percentiles],
            label='given percentiles')
xs = np.linspace(stats.norm(*fit_params).ppf(0.001), stats.norm(*fit_params).ppf(0.999), 500)
plt.plot(xs, stats.norm(*fit_params).cdf(xs), 'b--',
         label=f'fit ppf: $\\mu={fit_params_ppf[0]:.2f}, \\sigma={fit_params_ppf[1]:.2f}$')

fit_params_cdf, _fit_covariances = optimize.curve_fit(lambda x, mu, sigma: stats.norm(mu, sigma).cdf(x),
                                                      xdata=[percentile for percent, percentile in percentiles],
                                                      ydata=[percent for percent, percentile in percentiles],
                                                      p0=[16, 8])
plt.plot(xs, stats.norm(*fit_params).cdf(xs), 'r:',
         label=f'fit cdf: $\\mu={fit_params_cdf[0]:.2f}, \\sigma={fit_params_cdf[1]:.2f}$')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. I just got the chance to test your suggestion.